# How do I center align a table column in restructured text?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Here's what I tried:

```
.. tabularcolumns:: |L|C|L|

.. csv-table::
    :header: 1, 2, 3

    1, 2, 3
    very very long, very very long, very very long

.. tabularcolumns:: |L|C|L|

+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| Head 1         | Head 2         | Head 3         |
+================+================+================+
| 1              |              2 | 3              |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| very very long | very very long | very very long |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Neither works. Column 2 is left aligned, not right.

Comment: Are you generating HTML or LaTeX? It appears that `tabularcolumns` applies only to LaTeX. For HTML, I would suggest using a CSS selector for the second column to center-align it.

Comment: It's weird that there is no output agnostic way of doing it.

Comment: Steve Piercy, do you happen to know how to assign a special class to that column?

Comment: Not to the column, but the table with `:class:`. Nonetheless you can use the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector to select the Nth `th` and `td` in each row.